# Flutter mailer package is not sending mail with my custom Smtp server

Tags: flutter, dart, smtp, mailer

I am trying to send a mail with the mailer package in Flutter but I am getting this error:
`[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER(tls_record.cc:242))`.

I am using the port 587. If I am sending the mail on port 465 I am getting the message that the mail is sent but there is nothing in my inbox. Even in the spam folder.

These are the mail settings I need to use from my provider:

Outgoing mail:

- server: mail.yourcloudweb.com
- port: 587 / 465
- type encryption: STARTTLS, TLS of SSL
- verification required: yes
- username: e-mailadres
- password: password

Here is my code:

```
mailtest() async {
  String username = 'my-emailaddress';
  String password = 'my-password';

  final smtpServer = SmtpServer(
    'mail.yourcloudweb.com',
    port: 587,
    ignoreBadCertificate: false,
    ssl: true,
    username: username,
    password: password
  );

  // Create our message.
  final message = Message()
    ..from = Address(username, 'Your name')
    ..recipients.add('rens@lakens.org')
    ..subject = 'Test Dart Mailer library ::  :: ${DateTime.now()}'
    ..text = 'This is the plain text.\nThis is line 2 of the text part.'
    ..html = "<h1>Test</h1>\n<p>Hey! Here's some HTML content</p>";

  try {
    final sendReport = await send(message, smtpServer);
    print('Message sent: ' + sendReport.toString());
  } on MailerException catch (e) {
    print('Message not sent.');
    for (var p in e.problems) {
      print('Problem: ${p.code}: ${p.msg}');
    }
  }
}

class Mail extends StatefulWidget {
  const Mail({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Mail> createState() => _MailState();
}

class _MailState extends State<Mail> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Mailtest"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: mailtest, child: Text("Send mail"))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you don't have a TLS version which is acceptable to the server.

Comment: And how would I do that in my application?

Comment: It's unrelated to your application, it's about the local SSL library version, if my hunch is correct.

Comment: I've tried multiple servers on different domains and it's still not working. How would I fix my issue?